# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: attributes, database

I found this sql query :

```
UPDATE IGNORE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET store_id =0 WHERE attribute_id = <my_attribute_id>
```

I replace "my_attribute_id by "Brand", where Brand is the attribute_id

so I am running following query :

```
UPDATE IGNORE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET store_id =0 WHERE attribute_id = <brand>
```

but i am getting following error :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<cost>' at line 1
```

please help me to find proper query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to omit the braces `<` `>`. They were just there to emphasize that this is a variable

```
UPDATE IGNORE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET store_id =0 WHERE attribute_id = xy;
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'brand' in 'where clause'  now i am facing this error

Comment: ah it's early :x  brand is the attribute_code. you have to insert the attribute_id there. You can get the attribute id from the table eav_attribute (search for attribute_code brand) or from the url when you are in this attributes settings (right behind the id part is the actual id)

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply query like this,You can't keep `brand` text in query because in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table doesn't accept attribute_id as text or string value its type is smallint. so you must enter your brand attribute id from `Catalog -> Manage Attributes` section.
Here, for example brand id is 111 then you have keep below query,

```
 UPDATE IGNORE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET store_id =0 WHERE attribute_id = 111;
```